# How do I add this module to my customized version of Alfresco without a global trashcan

Tags: alfresco

I deleted a piece of data on the Alfresco page, and I want to restore the data, but my Alfresco is customized without user configuration options, and I can't see the global trashcan can, what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Try to access user trashcan URL directly.

like --> <IP_Address/DNS>/share/page/user/<user_id>/user-trashcan

Comment: It seems that my alfresco settings do not enable the global trash can function, because I do not display the entries I deleted under share/page/user/admin/user-trashcan. Do you know how to set the feature to activate